# Using jQuery JSON function to populate textarea when a specific dropdown item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, populate

I might sound as completely noob, but could you help me with this?

I have a form with dropdown select and within a lot of text area boxes.

**What I need:**
When a specific option is selected, I'd like to populate all text area with some text (using JSON).

Code:

**HTML**

```
<label>name</label>
<select>
<option value="0" data-num="">name lastname</option>
<option value="1" data-num="">name lastname</option>
<option value="2" data-num="">name lastname</option>
<option value="3" data-num="">name lastname</option>
</select>


<textarea name="name"></textarea>
<textarea name="applicant"></textarea>
<textarea name="applicant_en"></textarea>
<textarea name="email"></textarea>
<textarea name="vat"></textarea>
<textarea name="rc"></textarea>
```

**JSON data**

```
{
"id":["1","2"],
"name":["John Doe","John notDoe"],
"applicant":["lorem ipsum","second"],
"applicant_en":["one","two"],
"email":["mail","mail_two"],
"vat":[61388963,4684645456],
"rc":["123456/0123","87986454/554"]
}"
```

I've tried something, but I gave up.. Could anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="some_id">
<option value="0" data-num="">name lastname</option>
<option value="1" data-num="">name lastname</option>
<option value="2" data-num="">name lastname</option>
<option value="3" data-num="">name lastname</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$("#some_id").on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()==1){

       $("input[name='applicant']).val("fetched from json");

    }
   ///else continue with other values
})
```

EDIT : 
provide some id or class to your html.

```
<textarea name="applicant" id="applicant"></textarea>
```

In JS :

```
populate('#MyForm', $.parseJSON(data));



function populate(strFormId,jsonData){

    $(strFormId+' #applicant').val(jsonData.applicant[0] +' '+jsonData.applicant[1]);

//do in the same way for other DOM element.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!
However, I have to ask. Would you know how to do that, so I can just add json data for example like this:

`var data = '{"applicant":"Hello","email":"world"}';` 

`populate('#MyForm', $.parseJSON(data));`

Comment: Ok, here is the JS solution from your first answer - https://jsfiddle.net/rkqkaptq/3/
That is working, but I can't do the part with parsing data via JSON.. :(

Comment: I think I've got it, so i mark this answer as the right one since it really help me.Thanks